# PHP - Filter an array string alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array of strings

```
$cities = ['New York', 'Boston', 'Los Angeles', 'Cincinnati', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', 'Seattle'];
```

I want to retrieve all the strings that starts with letter A, then B, then C, and so on for each alphabet letters.

What is the best way to do it avoing useless code repetitions?

Comment: have you tried doing it yourself?

Comment: Question, do you have it?

Comment: Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary multidimensional array with first letter as index. Try -

```
$cities = ['New York', 'Boston', 'Los Angeles', 'Cincinnati', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', 'Seattle'];

foreach($cities as $city) {
    $first = substr($city, 0, 1);
    $temp_cities[$first][] = $city;
}

var_dump($temp_cities);
```

**Output**

```
array(8) {
  ["N"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "New York"
  }
  ["B"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Boston"
  }
  ["L"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Los Angeles"
  }
  ["C"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Cincinnati"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Chicago"
  }
  ["H"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Houston"
  }
  ["P"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Philadelphia"
  }
  ["D"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Dallas"
  }
  ["S"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Seattle"
  }
}
```

To find cities start with 'C' do - `var_dump($temp_cities['C'])`

Comment: Thanks that solves my question and seems to me the best way to do it. My point was to avoid useless code repetitions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($cities, function($a, $b){
    return $a <=> $b;
});
```

Comment: Or, y'know, just `sort($cities)`. But either way sorting isn't what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php

$cities = ['New York', 'Boston', 'Los Angeles', 'Cincinnati', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', 'Seattle'];
$new_array = [];
$search_string = 'C'; // Letter to search
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    if (strpos($city, $search_string) === 0) {
        $new_array[] = $city;
    }
}
print_r($new_array);// New array will contian list of identified cities
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort array with

```
$cities = ['New York', 'Boston', 'Los Angeles', 'Cincinnati', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', 'Seattle'];

sort($cities);
```

Comment: Please post documentation links to the actual [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) rather than a third party site

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to create 26 arrays, one for each letter of the alphabet, each array containing cities starting with that letter.

```
<?php
    $cities = ['New York', 'Boston', 'Los Angeles', 'Cincinnati', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', 'Seattle'];

    //Our 26 arrays
    $arrA = array();
    $arrB = array();
    $arrC = array();
    $arrD = array();
    $arrE = array();
    $arrF = array();
    $arrG = array();
    $arrH = array();
    $arrI = array();
    $arrJ = array();
    $arrK = array();
    $arrL = array();
    $arrM = array();
    $arrN = array();
    $arrO = array();
    $arrP = array();
    $arrQ = array();
    $arrR = array();
    $arrS = array();
    $arrT = array();
    $arrU = array();
    $arrV = array();
    $arrW = array();
    $arrX = array();
    $arrY = array();
    $arrZ = array();

    //Fill the array for that city.
    foreach ($cities as $city){
        $key = substr($city, 0, 1);
        ${"arr".$key}[] = $city;
    }
    //Let's just test this worked.
    var_dump($arrC);
    var_dump($arrB);
    var_dump($arrN);

?>
```

Comment: Using multidimensional array is better than 26 separate variable

Comment: @Mohammad I agree that would be better, but it's not what the OP asked for.